# Find a number $b$ consisting of 39 ones and as few zeros as possible such that digitsum($b$) = 39 and gcd($b$,rev($b$)) = 39

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I try to find term #16 of OEIS sequence A348480 (https://oeis.org/A348480). It must fulfill these constraints:

digitsum($b$) = 39 and gcd($b$,rev($b$)) = 39

where rev(x) is the digital reverse of x (e.g. rev(123) = 321).
The smallest $b$ I found is:

10000010000010000010000010000010000011000011000011100011100011100111100111100111100111100111100

It has 95 digits (39 ones and 56 zeros), but for sure, there is a smaller $b$.

Comment: I wonder what makes you sure that there must be better solutions, but in fact there are. My current record is $$111111110100111000111101111000111101111101110100111000111$$ with $57$ digits

Comment: Thanks Peter! I did some more search in the meantime, and I am pretty sure that this is the smallest solution: 1000111000111000111001111101111101111101111101111101111. It has 55 digits (16 zeros). By the way, if you turn your number around, the solution is already a bit smaller :-)

Comment: I ran my (random) search program about half an hour and found no solution better than the one I mentioned. Hence , your number could actually be optimal.